# Show name of the place with Google Directions API

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am trying to make a request to the Google Directions API with multiple waypoints. Everything works fine so far, but the main problem that I'm having is that when the Google Maps app is open for the user, all that the user can see are the coordinates.

I am working on a Flutter App, but probably this request is the same for all devices and platforms, so it's not really Flutter-specific.

I want to show the name of the companies/places on the route.

It could be either a web request or a request using the URL scheme for the Google Maps mobile app.

This is what I'm doing so far, with the coordinates.

```
  Future<void> launchGoogleMaps(BuildContext context) async {
    Position userLocation = await Geolocator().getLastKnownPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
    );

    String googleMapsAppUrl = 'comgooglemapsurl://?';

    if (customFirstPlace != null) {
      googleMapsAppUrl +=
          "saddr=${customFirstPlace.latitude},${customFirstPlace.longitude}";
    } else if (!shouldStartWithUserLocation) {
      googleMapsAppUrl +=
          "saddr=${circuitCompanies[0].lat},${circuitCompanies[0].lng}";
    }

    String googleMapsWebUrl = "http://www.google.com/maps/dir";
    googleMapsWebUrl += "/${userLocation.latitude},${userLocation.longitude}";

    circuitCompanies.forEach((CompanyModel element) {
      int elementIndex = circuitCompanies.indexOf(element);
      // If it's the first element, the "direction"
      // parameter will be added to specify the beginning.
      // If not, the "to" parameter will be added
      // to specify a waypoint (a stop).

      if (elementIndex == 0) {
        googleMapsAppUrl += "&daddr=${element.lat},${element.lng}";
      } else {
        googleMapsAppUrl += "+to:${element.lat},${element.lng}";
      }

      googleMapsWebUrl += "/${element.lat},${element.lng}";
    });

    if (await canLaunch("comgooglemaps://")) {
      print('launching com googleUrl $googleMapsAppUrl');
      await launch(googleMapsAppUrl);
    } else if (await canLaunch(googleMapsWebUrl)) {
      print('launching web url $googleMapsWebUrl');
      await launch(googleMapsWebUrl);
    } else {
      showDialog(
        builder: (_) {
          return SingleActionDialog(
            title: "Erreur",
            onConfirmTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            bodyText: "Un erreur s'est produit.",
            confirmText: "Fermer",
          );
        },
        context: context,
      );
    }
  }
```

How could I show the appropriate route, with the name of the places that the user will go, instead of only showing the coordinates? I have access to the precise place address as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. I instead used the web URL provided by the Google Maps API.

I made a function that returns the address of the place following the Google Maps standard, instead of just passing coordinates.

```
 Future<String> getEncodedCompanyAddress(CompanyModel model)  async {
String _encodedAddress = "";

model.address = await CompanyAddressDAO().getCompanyAddress(
  model.id,
);

_encodedAddress = model.details.title +
    ", " +
    model.address.street +
    ", " +
    model.address.city +
    ", " +
    model.address.state;

_encodedAddress = Uri.encodeFull(_encodedAddress);

_encodedAddress = _encodedAddress.replaceAll("%20", "+");

return _encodedAddress;
```

}

Now, instead of showing only the coordinates, the actual place name is shown in the directions of the Google Maps app.